# Qt installer framework mac desktop alias

Tags: c++, macos, alias, desktop, qt-installer

I have create some application installer for mac using Qt installer framework.

Application installed fine but I want to add some desktop shortcut (alias) for my app. There is a lot of instructions how create it by Finder, but no one how create it by Qt installer framework or SH script (for that created while installation). So my question.

Is it possible to create desktop shortcut (alias) on MAC by Qt installer framework or some SH script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very strange for my developer experience, but it real work. I have found answer here 
[How do I create a Macintosh Finder Alias From the Command Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072208/how-do-i-create-a-macintosh-finder-alias-from-the-command-line)

this SH command real work.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to make alias file to POSIX file "/file/to/make/link/from" at POSIX file "/folder/where/to/make/link"'
```